# Apex Export with Sequences

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to export an APEX application which uses some sequences and then install this onto a new APEX system. However everything is working except the sequences as they seem to not be included in the install file.

Answer (score 2):

Exporting an apex application only exports the apex application. Database objects, such as sequences and packages, are not exported.

You could use the "Supporting Objects" feature of the application to create installation scripts as part of the application.
Within an application, choose "Supporting Objects". Select "Installation Scripts". Click "Create". Choose "Create from Database Object".  You can then add objects to the script. Eventually an SQL file will be created and added to the application.
Exporting the application will then include the supporting objects scripts, and you'll get the option to install these when you import the application.
However (!), these scripts are **NOT** updated as you alter objects in the database. You'll have to recreate the scripts all the time.
I'm not a big fan of this way though. It's okay for a small app. Or if you have an app you'd want to distribute. I much prefer separate sql files for objects required.
**If you're serious about your development you will treat apex and the database objects as separate entities.** There's a reason why almost all apex developers try to keep their code out of apex where reasonable.

Other options are: export objects through sql developer (or toad, whatever floats your boat). You can easily create all the scripts for all the different types of objects.
Maintaining these files separately will also allow putting them in version-management much easier. When all your install scripts are in the apex application, not so much.